# Failing composition of functorial and monadic operations

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, function-composition

Another newbie question in my struggle to learn idiomatic Haskell: I'm trying to compose a smart constructor out of some validation functions, but I can't get the types to line up.

This is the type I want to construct:

```
newtype Tag = Tag { getTag :: Text }
```

These are the validation functions:

```
validateCharacters :: Text -> Maybe Text
canonicalize :: Text -> Text
validateTagLength :: Text -> Maybe Text
```

And here is the smart constructor I'm trying to write:

```
mkTag t = Tag
       <$> validateTagLength
       >=> canonicalize
       <$> validateCharacters t
```

To my understanding, the types should add up: `canonicalize <$> validateCharacters` is of type `Text -> Maybe Text`, as is `validateTagLength`, and the Kleisil fish is supposed to combine monadic functions `a -> m b`. Finally, mapping the constructor over the resulting `Maybe` monad should return the expected `Maybe Tag`. However, I get the following type errors:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe Text’ with ‘Text’
      Expected type: Text -> Text
        Actual type: Text -> Maybe Text
    • In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘validateTagLength’
      In the first argument of ‘(>=>)’, namely
        ‘UnconstrainedTag <$> validateTagLength’
    [...]
```

And

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b0 -> m c’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe Text’
    • Possible cause: ‘(<$>)’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(>=>)’, namely
        ‘canonicalize <$> validateCharacters t’
    [...]
```

Where is my mistake? Am I missing out on some precedence rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code uses `canonicalize <$> validateCharacters t` (note the final `t`!) which has type `Maybe Text` so you can't `>=>` it since it is not a function.

You could use something like

```
mkTag t :: Text -> Maybe Tag
mkTag t = do
   canonic <- canonicalize <$> validateCharacters t
   Tag <$> validateTagLength canonic
```

or

```
mkTag t :: Text -> Maybe Tag
mkTag t = Tag <$> ((canonicalize <$> validateCharacters t) >>= validateTagLength)
```

which is arguably less readable. Even using `=<<` to fix the order it looks worse than the `do` variant, in my opinion.

If you really want a point-free solution, perhaps this could also work, and it's not that bad:

```
mkTag = fmap Tag . validateTagLength <=< fmap canonicalize . validateCharacters
```

Comment: I suspected something along those lines. But eta reduction (leaving out the `t` on both sides) does not type-check either. So, where is the problem, why do I need do notation?

Comment: @UlrichSchuster You can't eta reduce that, it's not of the form `f x = g x` but something like `f x = h (g x)` where `h` involves `<$>`, `>=>` etc. You don't need `do` but I feel the other forms will be less readable.

Comment: So, the problem essentially is that I cannot define  `mkTag'  = canonicalize <$> validateCharacters`, because I cannot map over a function? Hence, I cannot use `(>=>)`; instead, I need an operator that takes a value instead of a function, which would be reverse bind, I suppose.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster You can map over a function, but that will use the `(->) a` functor instead of the `Maybe` functor you want. You can use `>=>` only if both sides have type `a -> Maybe b` and `b -> Maybe c`. See my last (untested) attempt above which is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks very much, I think I got it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a strict left-to-right "pipeline", you need to turn `canonicalize` into a Kleisli arrow (i.e., switch from `a -> b` to `a -> Maybe b`) by composing it with `return`. You also have to apply `validateTagLength` to `t` first, to "prime" the pipeline.

```
mkTag t = Tag <$> (validateTagLength t
                   >>= return . canonicalize
                   >>= validateCharacters)
```

You can make this point-free using `>=>`, creating a Kleisli arrow from `Tag` as well.

```
mkTag = validateTagLength
        >=> return . canonicalize
        >=> validateCharacters
        >=> return . Tag
```

(You might find it more readable to define `klift = (return .)`, letting you write `mkTag = validateTagLength >=> klift canonicalize >=> ...`.)

However, there's nothing wrong with

```
mkTag t = do
    t1 <- validateTagLength t
    let t2 = canonicalize t1
    t3 <- validateCharacters t2
    return $ Tag t3
```

Comment: Also thanks a lot. The two replies have cleared up my thinking.